# API for GDIObject count for different GDIObjects?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, gdi, win32gui

I have made a WinForm Application which can take GDIObject count of a running process through GetGuiResources WIn32 API at any point via PInvoke, through this i take GDIObject count and like this i do some iterations of workflow and put it in an excel which creates a graph by which i can analyze if there is any leak in a process but i want different graphs for each GDIObject like pens, brushes, fonts, palettes, regions, device contexts, bitmap headers so that i can get different graphs of all GDIObjects respectively so the question is that is there any API through which i can get GDIObject count for different GDIObjects. 
I came across this link:
[How to get list of GDI handles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905661/how-to-get-list-of-gdi-handles)

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsui_team/archive/2013/04/23/debugging-a-gdi-resource-leak.aspx : *"There are more, or you could write your own and use the above as reference (see below).You can do this yourself, but it involves some tricks.  The most important thing you’ll need is the address of the GDI handle table in User Memory.  Though undocumented, this can be obtained by looking for GdiSharedHandleTable inside the process environment block (the PEB).  This field contains the address for the handle table. "*

Comment: You are inventing a wheel.  Google "gdileaks".

Comment: Given link is for getting all GDI handles separately http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905661/how-to-get-list-of-gdi-handles